# How to use RRO(Runtime Resource Overlay) in Android12?

Tags: android, android-source

As far as I know, when overlay APK is enabled, the application will refresh the UI by rebuilding the activity. This was true before Android 11, and the relevant code is as follows:

[image]

However, in Android 12, Google removed this line of code:

[image]

After actual testing on Android 12, it was found that after enable overlay APK, the system app activity will not be relaunch, only non system app will.
Checked and found that the activity was rebuilt using another method.

[image]

[image]

In the initialization function, WindowProcessController will determine whether uid is a system process. If it is a system application, mIsActivityConfigOverrideAllowed will be set false, resulting in the system app unable to relaunch activity after override.

"This is a system owned process and should not use an activity config."
What is the meaning of this annotation?

How should I modify the source code so that both system and non system apps can relaunch activity？
I tried adding code from Android 11 to the handleApplicationInfoChanged method, but it caused another bug where non system applications were sometimes recreated twice